# How to hide a variable?

Tags: javascript, php, apache

Sry, i can't find anything on google related to my issue.

I have an API key which I don't want to publicy known. But somewhere I have to store it. What's a safe way? I have already read about environment variables but I have no clue how to do that (since google isn't helping either).

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you asking about client side JavaScript, server side JavaScript or server side PHP? Your tags are unclear.

Comment: And you want to hide variable from who?

Comment: is this to be used on server side? you can have it in a separate server-side code encrypt it and make a call to it when you need and then decrypt it.

Comment: Of course serverside. Otherwise people could see my API key with a source code viewer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of environment variables using the getenv function.

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/es/function.getenv.php

And on your development environment you can use phpdotenv for simplicity.

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv